# Convert the IP Address range to two BIGINT for faster lookup

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, geolocation

I am working on a project in which we need to do `IP Address lookups`. So for this we have got the datasets which will look like below and now the next steps is to populate this datasets (may be a csv file) in to the `MySql table`. Below is the dataset example containing columns-

```
ip_address      country region  city           metro-code   latitude    longitude   postal-code   country-code   region-code    city-code   continent-code  country-code

24.32.116.116   usa       tx    clarksville    623           33.6103    -95.0498    75426            840           44             34918            6            us
65.29.108.232   usa       mi    novi           505           42.4637    -83.4604    48375            840           23             4339             6            us
66.169.99.69    usa       tx    ft worth       623           32.7016    -97.3823    76109            840           44             771              6            us
72.70.100.111   usa       ma    peabody        506           42.5332    -70.9726    1960             840           22             1392             6            us
174.252.116.137 usa       va    oakton         511           38.8892    -77.3222    22124            840           47             3860             6            us
68.55.144.242   usa       md    pasadena       512           39.1276    -76.5125    21122            840           21             4358             6            us
174.252.83.27   usa       pa    lancaster      566           40.0459    -76.3542    17603            840           39             333              6            us
174.78.192.31   usa       ga    warner robins  503           32.5958    -83.6384    31088            840           11             5052             6            us
98.192.146.235  usa       fl    panama city    656           30.1804    -85.5598    32404            840           10             671              6            us
71.192.181.20   usa       ma    springfield    543           42.1187    -72.5483    1109             840           22             967              6            us
76.183.54.227   usa       tx    dallas         623           32.7202    -96.6769    75217            840           44             77               6            us
69.62.143.140   usa       ca    granite bay    862           38.7442    -121.191    95746            840           5              49451            6            us
69.142.76.32    usa       nj    penns grove    504           39.707     -75.4467    8069             840           31             2335             6            us
70.173.54.93    usa       nv    las vegas      839           36.2059    -115.225    89108            840           29             173              6            us
98.242.8.222    usa       ca    fresno         866           36.7968    -119.883    93722            840           5              19               6            us
```

**Problem Statement:-**

I am planning to store the `START_IP_NUM` and `END_IP_NUM` as `BIGINT` in the MySql database instead of storing `IP Address` in the table as doing a lookup against a BIGINT is far faster than searching a string (dotted ip notation). Just like we have database setup for Maxmind.

So my question is we will be having separate `Java Program` that will populate the above datasets in the MySql table. So I need to device some sort of logic which can convert the above datasets into like below-

```
start_ip_num
end_ip_num
country 
region  
city           
metro-code  
latitude    
longitude   
postal-code   
country-code     
region-code 
city-code   
continent-code  
country-code
```

I am confuse given a IP Address how should I device `start_ip_num` and `end_ip_num` here and store it into the `MySql table`. As there will be a file I am assuming which will contain the datasets like above and then I need to read that file and device some sort of logic to convert the IP Address to two BIGINT and store it into the MySql table.

And after storing it into MySql database. I can do lookup something like this in MySql-

```
SELECT country
FROM geoip
WHERE
INET_ATON('174.36.207.186') BETWEEN start_ip_num AND end_ip_num
LIMIT 1
```

**UPDATE:-**

Suppose I have around couple of `Thousands IP Address` like `100,000 IP Addresses` in a text file with the format I mentioned above.

Now my main Objective is to do the `IP Address lookup`. Corresponding to this `IP Address` get me all the other required fields.

So to make this thing work, I was initially planning to dump the text file data as it is in the `MySql table`. So MySql table will contain `IP Address` column and other columns just like I have in the above example. But doing a lookup on the String is expensive.

So I thought I should convert those IP Address in `start_ip_num` and `end_ip_num` range and then dump the data in `MySql table` so now it will look something like this-

```
start_ip_num
end_ip_num
country 
region  
city           
metro-code  
latitude    
longitude   
postal-code   
country-code     
region-code 
city-code   
continent-code  
country-code
```

And now if I need to do the lookups, I can have this `SQL query` embedded in my `WebService eventually`-

```
SELECT country
FROM geoip
WHERE
INET_ATON('174.36.207.186') BETWEEN start_ip_num AND end_ip_num
LIMIT 1
```

**So question is-** Given a `Text file` which will have list of `IP Addresses` and other fields corresponding to that `IP Address` how should I massage it in such a way such that I can store the same datasets in MySql in the format I mentioned above such as `start_ip_num` and `end_ip_num`, `country` and other fields.

Basically I am trying to follow the pattern of database such as Maxmind have currently. They also have `start_ip_num` and `end_ip_num` and other fields. And when you need to do the lookups you can do the lookups basis on the SQL I mentioned above by converting the IP Address to `BIGINT` using `INET_ATON`.

Comment: Why not store it as an integer?  IPv4 addresses are guaranteed not to exceed 8 bytes.

Comment: @Makoto i'd say IPv4 addresses are guaranteed to be 4 bytes.

Comment: I upvoted suggestion with IPv4 and 4 bytes, but... maybe its good to have IPv6 support in new application?

Comment: Yeah we are thinking of IPv6 support as well. If we decide to go with IPv6 then anything has to be changed in my table?

Comment: @TechGeeky If you want to support IPv6 address, as well, then have the column be a 128-bit integer column. Then, maybe have another 1-char column that specify whether the address integer represents IPv4 or IPv6 address so that you can cast the value therein accordingly.

Comment: I see. I will keep a note of this. IPv6 support we need to do in future cases. For now I am mainly focusing on how to Import above datasets in MySql db with start_ip_num and end_ip_num.

Comment: @nos, Yeah but how to get start_ip_num and end_ip_num. I can get only single BIGINT for IPAddress but how to have ranges of start_ip_num and end_ip_num? That is confusing me.

Comment: @techgeeky does the file you have above list all individual IP addresses and you want to merge identical rows to a single row in the database? Eg file contains 123.5.7.2 Houston and 123.5.7.3 Houston as two lines but you want a single line in the database? I'm not completely understanding your question given your comment on my answer.

Comment: @nos, I just updated my question with more details. Let me know if still it is not clear. I have tried my best to provide all the details.

Comment: @rlb, I just updated my question with more details. Let me know if still it is not clear. I have tried my best to provide all the details.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 addresses contain 4 numbers, each of which can range from 0...255

You can convert an address A.B.C.D to a 32 bit integer ( or bigint if you prefer ) with this logic

```
Result = (A<<24) | (B<<16) | (C<<8) | D
```

Where A,B,C,D are integers.  This is the method we use, and I think this was even originally tested against MaxMind. (apologies if not exactly java example)

Comment: Thanks but how to get start_ip_num and end_ip_num. I can get only single BIGINT for IPAddress from the above example right? But how to have ranges of start_ip_num and end_ip_num? That is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to make some sort of hard relationship between an IpAddress and its physical location in the world.  For example, if two closely related IpAdresses are from New York, then any IpAdresse with a value between these two IpAdresse should also be from New York; right?

Wrong!

The distribution of IP addresses over the world is totally arbitrary and while IP addresses are usually distributed in block to a Country, District, Big Company, etc.; what happens after that is more or less arbitrary.  For example, big companies like Microsoft and Google have their own blocks of IP addresses; however, what they do with it is totally arbitrary and what Microsoft choose to do with one IP address can be totally different from the next or the previous address. It's even possible that one IP address will point toward a country one day and another country the next day because there has been a change in the network topology.

Making a relationship between an IP address and its physical location requires a very extensive database and even in this case, is very prone to errors and daily changes.  Even the database used by Google is probably filled with errors; despites its extensive datas.

Answer (score 0):

You have raw data in IP address and you would like it to represent in range format. Here is the flowchart of how it should work.

1) Convert all IP address to IP number
2) Sort the IP number ascending
3) Scan through records and compress the record with same city

For example, IP 1 and IP 2 is in city X. You can represent it as 1,2,X.

The assumption here is you have almost all the IP address. If there is a missing gap between 2 numbers, you need to assume it is from the same city X. For instance, IP 1 and IP 3 is in city X, you are assuming IP 2 in X as well. 1,3,X.